# How to make offscreen UIScrollView aware of device rotations?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, screen-rotation

I have watched the WWDC session 223 video on using the `panGestureRecognizer` of an off screen `UIScrollView` to get kinetic scrolling in OpenGL.
I'm experimenting with this and a `UIView` descendant (rather than the OpenGL view in the demo)
All works fine except when I rotate the device, the scrollview still calculates the `contentOffset` in unrotated coordinates. Is there any way to instruct/hook up the scroll view to the apply the device rotation / window transformations?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Turn out I did not watch the demo video carefully enough: the scrollview must be hooked up to the root controler by adding it as a child view. Adding the UIScrollView as an invisible child to the UIVIew it controls fixed the problem.

```
UIView* theViewToControl = [...];
UIScrollView* scroller = [....];
// move gesture recognizer, set delegate etc. 
// Up to here it works, except for rotations;
// This is is required to make rotations work too:
[scroller setHidden:YES];
[theViewToControl addSubView:scroller];
```